# Why does the child process inherit `sys.modules` when forking processes Linux but not in Macos

Tags: python, process, python-multiprocessing

When using multiprocessing on different platforms, the way `sys.modules` is handled seems to be different. If you modify the `sys.modules` dict on Linux, and spawn a child process, that process seems inherit the dict, but in Macos a new object is created for `sys.modules`. Is this because the way multiprocessing works is not OS-agnostic?

Is this due to Linux using `fork()` when creating a child process and Macos doing it differently?

For example, if I try this snippet:

```py
import multiprocessing
import sys
import time
from types import ModuleType


def worker():
    # print the id of the dict
    print('worker', id(sys.modules), 'foo' in sys.modules)


def main():
    # modify the sys.modules dict
    sys.modules['foo'] = ModuleType('foo')

    # print the id of the dict
    print('main', id(sys.modules), 'foo' in sys.modules)

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, daemon=True)
    p.start()

    time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get these results:

**Linux (x86_64, python 3.10.1)**

```
main 139897509461248 True
worker 139897509461248 True
```

**Macos (M1 ARM, python 3.10.1)**

```
main 4307217856 True
worker 4334595520 False
```

For context: I am trying to build a task queue using just the stdlib (ala Celery). However, I could not find an idiomatic way to pass pickled functions to worker processes, but in most cases, I get that attribute lookup fails when unpickling the serialized functions (when serializing callables, pickle just stores the name and module, and this is loaded at runtime when deserializing).

A workaround I'm trying is to change the function's `__module__` attribute when serializing the function, and adding it to a dynamically created module. This seems to fix the attribute lookup error, but feels like a bad hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MacOS new multi-processing processes are spawned and not forked by default. This is less efficient and includes a re-import of packages and modules.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods):

> Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the
> default. The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can
> lead to crashes of the subprocess. See bpo-33725.

You can try [`multiprocessing.set_start_method()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) at your own risk.